# java pick a random class/object

Tags: java, arrays, object, random

Is there a way to pick a random object from an array of objects?

I have tried a few ways that I could think of but none work.
I want to use a function in the random class (all classes will have the same function but different returns).

I should have mentioned i am trying to return an image, and each time i try to return a random image it doesnt return anyting ("null")

Here is some of my code I am having the problem with:

```
    Car car;
    Ford ford;
    Mazda mazda
    Fiat fiat
    Rover rover   

    Car carlist[] = {ford,fiat,mazda,rover}

public void paint(){
//this displays an image every 128 pixles 
        for (int i = 0;i<Width;i+=128){

            for(int j=128; j<Height;j+=128){
// this draws the image (the image is declaired in each car's class as getImage)
                g.drawImage((car.carList[rand.nextInt(5)]).getImage(), i, j , this);
                    }
                }
```

The code works if i put an object in (instead of carcarList[rand.nextInt(5)])).
Each of the cartypes extend Cars.

Comment: What ways have you tried? Post your code that you're having trouble with

Comment: Generate a random integer between `0` and `length - 1` (where `length` is the length of your array), and use that as the index to access the array to retrieve your object.

Comment: I would post the code but currently on a mobile device and don't have it handy sorry

Comment: It returns *null* because ford, fiat, mazda and rover are all *null*. You never created such objects. To create them, do `Ford ford = new Ford();`. And this has nothing to do with Java btw...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `yourList` is the array of your objects, use this single line:

```
Object randomObj = yourList[(int)Math.random() * list.length];
```

Comment: Unnecessary multiplication and conversion from double to int. Use `Random` class instead.

Comment: @aioobe Math.random does not return an int

Answer (score 2):

You could use `java.util.Random`'s method `nextInt()` to generate a random index into the array. The method takes an argument specifying the `maximum - 1` value that is returned: specify the `length` of the array:

```
// Member variables.
Object[] arr = ...;
Random r = new Random();

Object nextRandmonObject()
{
    return arr[r.nextInt(arr.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it like this by using the [`Random` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

```
String rndStr = yourArray[new Random().nextInt(yourArray.length)];
```

If you need to do it repeatedly you should consider having a `Random` as a member variable and reusing the same instance for your calls to `nextInt`.

Answer (score 0):

You could let them all implement the same interface then just randomice to selcet the class.
Some very unchecked pseudocode for this:

```
public class  myclass1 implements RandomInterface {}


public class  myclass2 implements RandomInterface {}

public interface RandomInterface {
    public void doStuff1();
    pubilc String doStuff2();
}

    public class random{
        RandomInterface randomObj = yourList[(int)Math.random() * list.length];
        randomObj.doStuff1();
        randomObj.doStuff2();

    }
```

Comment: Wow, too much complicated for a such a simple question.

Comment: since he/she wants to call a method on the random class i can only see that this is the way or go with a instanceof solution?

Comment: Oh I think you misunderstood... "he/she wants to call a method on the random class" With this he/she means the `java.util.Random` class :) I'm removing downvote ;)

Comment: hehe okej, thats a bit different =)

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy:

```
Object your_array[];
[...]
Random rnd = new Random();
Object random_element = your_array[rnd.nextInt(your_array.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
    String[] a = new String[]{"1","2","3","4"};
    Random rand = new Random();
    String arbit = a[rand.nextInt(a.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

All your objects have a function that returns something, so let them implement this interface:

```
public interface ObjectReturningSomething
{
    Object theFunction();
}
```

Then your objects will be of classes like this, with functions returning different kinds of objects:

```
public class ObjectReturningString implements ObjectReturningSomething
{
    String theFunction() { return "Foo"; }
}
public class ObjectReturningInteger implements ObjectReturningSomething
{
    Integer theFunction() { return 42; }
}
```

Here's an array of such objects:

```
ObjectReturningSomething[] objectArray = new ObjectReturningSomething[] { new ObjectReturningString(), new ObjectReturningInteger() };
```

Here's how to pick a random one:

```
int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
ObjectReturningSomething randomObject = objectArray.get(randomIndex);
```

And here's how to call that function.

```
System.out.println(randomObject.theFunction());
```

Comment: Overcomplication. And it's `int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(array.length);`

Comment: `nextInt(array.length)` is indeed better, improved that. What part do you consider 'overcomplicated'? Your answer simply doesn't answer the question completely (it answers how to select a random object from a list, but not how to call a function on that object, which was part of the question).